# Labeling matlab plots with input parameters

Tags: global-variables

I am integrating a system of ode's using the MATLAB utility routine, ode45. I do not have a reliable way to label plots with the parameters used to produce the plotted results. It would be easy if there were a an approved substitute for global variables. It would be possible to write a script that automatically edits the derivative function for each case in order to hard-wire the constants, but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

To specify constants, simply add an equation for each constant and give 0 as its derivative. This adds a column to the result matrix but the constant value is available for use in calculating the other derivatives.